# PHP 7 opcache Linux folder permission issue

Tags: php, linux, opcache

I have this code in my php source file.

```
@copy($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], $tmpavatar)
```

The workdir has been set write permission by command `setfacl -R -m user:www:rwx folder`
Every thing goes well.

But when I delete the folder and remake a folder with command `rm -rf folder && mkdir folder && setfacl -R -m user:www:rwx folder`

Then the code above not work.

I must restart the `PHP-FPM` service and it works.

I wonder is it the issue about php 7 opcache ?

PS: php version: php 7.1.13

Comment: Why do you think it is related to the opcache?

Comment: [Opcache](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.opcache.php) uses memory, not disk.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using PHP's mkdir function?

Comment: Not related to the question but you should use [`move_uploded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) and not suppress the errors.

Comment: I use bash shell command to remove and re-make directory.Maybe it is not about opcache.But is it the PHP's issue?